# Returning Class from function

Tags: dart

Can someone explain why this does not work?

```
class Foo {
  Foo(this.foo);
  sayFoo() {
    print(foo);
  }
}

var test = () => Foo;
test()("blah").sayFoo(); // ERROR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart currently doesn't support constructor tear-offs, but it's planned to be added to the language eventually.

`test()` returns a `Type<Foo>`, but that doesn't allow you to invoke the constructor.

What you can do to simulate tear-offs is creating a closure

```
var test = (String foo) => Foo(foo);
test("blah").sayFoo(); // should work now
```

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't work because it isn't designed to work that way.

Comment: Try to answer with constructive answers, if possible with context ("why") or references to the language. Thanks!

Comment: Well, without a context of "why would you expect that to work", it's hard to answer why it doesn't work, except, yes, that's how it's designed.